# email text outputs as gibberish, with strange characters

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

outlook is outputting email text as gibberish in an occasional recevied email. e.g.  the body of the received email contains the following text "ÈI0 T„ŽE€ 8€Ò    €Ä".   when I view the same email through the web browser, the same text is outputted normally and says "I cud use a massage".  Please advise how I can change my OUtlook settings, so that the text will be not be oututted as gibberish
thank you very much

Comment: What you are experiencing is incorrectly detected character encoding. Every character is represented by a number by the computer and character encodings set the way numbers are translated into symbols. There are easy ways to change it in Outlook 2003, but I can't seem to find a way to do it in 2007 or 2010. If I find something, I'll be sure to post.